# Give a Spring WS dynamic-wsdl some style (using XSLT ?)

Tags: xslt, wsdl, spring-ws, html-generation

I'm currently trying to give my WSDLs some design by attaching a stylesheet to it, so that it could be readable by a technical but non-dev human being.
I was thinking I could add some XSLT to my generated spring-ws dynamic-wsdl so that it could be sent to the browser as a pure html (and not xml as it is). But I couldn't find any way to add xslt to the generated wsdl

Can you see any way to accomplish that ?

Comment: Most browsers will prettify the display of XML files, so a technical person will be able to read the WSDL returned in the browser with `?wsdl`. IDEs or text editors also have plugins to format XML files, or worse case scenario they can download it and upload it to an online XML formater. Unless you are doing this as a curiosity of how it can be done, there isn't really an use case here that needs addressing.

Comment: Hi. Not exactly my question. I edited to clarify my request. Thank you!